# Not getting param into bottomTabNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have login screen. I want to pass params/user) to my 2nd screen with 2 tabs in it. I don't know why but somehow I don't get params in my 2nd screen. I have custom header and there params is working perfectly.

App.js code:

```
const Routes = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Login: {
      screen: Login,

      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
          header: null,
        }),

    },
    Main: {
      screen: MainScreenRoutes,

      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
          header: null,
        }),
    },
});
```

How I navigate to Main from Login:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("Main",{user: JSON.stringify(obj)});
```

My main routes:

```
let headerDefaultHomeNavigationConfig = {
  header: props => <CustomHeaderMain {...props} />,
  ...HeaderStyles
}; 

let headerDefaultNavigationConfig = {
  header: props => <CustomHeader {...props} />,
  ...HeaderStyles
}; 


const Tab1 = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Domov: {
      screen: HomeScreen,
    },
  },
  {
     navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
       ...headerDefaultHomeNavigationConfig
      })
  } 
);

const Tab2 = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Dnevnik: {
      screen: Diary,

    }
  },
  {
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      ...headerDefaultNavigationConfig
    }), 

  }
);

const bottomTabs = createBottomTabNavigator(
{
  Domov: Tab1,
  Dnevnik: Tab2,
},
{
  initialRouteName: "Domov",
  navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      //header: null,
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
        const { routeName } = navigation.state;
        let iconName;
        if (routeName === 'Domov') {
          //iconName = `home${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
          iconName='home';
        } else if (routeName === 'Dnevnik') {
          //iconName = `ios-calendar${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
          iconName='ios-calendar';
        } 

        // if focused return view with line
        if(focused) {
          return (
            <View style={styles.item}>
                <Icon name={iconName} style={{fontSize: 20, color: '#FFF'}} />
                <View style={styles.line}></View>
            </View>
          );
        } else {
          return(
            <Icon name={iconName} style={{fontSize: 20, color: '#FFF'}} />
          )
        }

      },

    }),
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: 'white',
      showLabel: false,
      inactiveTintColor: '#4C2601',
      style: {
        backgroundColor: '#033D51',
      },
      labelStyle: {
        fontSize: 12,
        lineHeight: 30,
      },
    },
    swipeEnabled: true,

});
```

My HomeScreen constuctor:

```
export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {





    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            user: this.retrieveItem('user'),
        }   

        alert(JSON.stringify(this.props.navigation.state));

    }
```

In my 'Domov' screen I don't get my params, but in header there is params.

It looks like there is problem with navigation. I navigate to MAIN which is createbottomnavigation. And there I cannot get params...

If I changed my createbottomnavigation with this;

```
const bottomTabs = createBottomTabNavigator(
{
  Domov: HomeScreen,
  Dnevnik: Tab2,
},
);
```

Than I'm getting params to that screen. It looks like that stacknavigator canceled my params

Comment: Please share your `HomeScreen` component also

Comment: I posted...Check commment below

Comment: where are your imports in home page?

Comment: What imports? Please check again my post...I changed it...Looks like my stacknavigator for HomeScreen is doing some trouble

Answer (score 1):

You should be getting it, in your Login page, how do you receive your params?

It should be done like this:

```
const {params} = this.props.navigation.state
console.log(params.user)
```

Comment: I'm not getting any;

Comment: can you provide for your main and login components? it's impossible to help without knowing how you wrote them

Comment: alert(JSON.stringify(this.props.navigation.state)); my result is in HomeScreen;
{routeName:'domov',key:'id-12323543..'}

Comment: okay so you are navigating from `Login` page to `main` page? you have a `onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Main",{user: 'neki'})}` that you commented out. Then to receive it, in componentWillMount() in your `main` page, do exactly what I did in my answer. Refer to your console to see if it worked

Comment: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'params.user')

Comment: Looks like I need to pass props in createStackNavigator for each tab??

Comment: If you are passing something from the App.js file, then yes. But since you are passing something from the `Login` page, `this.props.navigation.navigate('Your Page', {user: 'someUser'})` should pass the prop `user` with the value of `'someUser'`

Comment: In app.js render() there is <routes />. Look code above...I don't know why I'm not getting params. I think problem is that I have separate createstacknavigator where is that HomeScreen